# React to unexpected errors

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, runtime-error

How do I react to an unexpected error on iOS?  For example:

```
func foo(a: Int, _ b: Int) {
  print(a / b)
}
//oops, this produces a divide by zero error.  How can I react to this
//unexpected error so I can report it to a remote server.
foo(1, 0)
```

---

Comment: You mean how do you catch unhandled exceptions?

Comment: Yea that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: Apple has a new way of handling errors with Swift 2.1 with do-catch, you can read about it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html)

Comment: So I have to put everything inside of a do catch?

Comment: I just tried wrapping foo inside of a do catch block.  The catch block is never it.  It seems like the do catch block isn't catching a divide by zero error.

Comment: Well it's a bit more involved than that, the link I gave is a pretty quick read and should help explain it a bit more. In your case, foo would know to throw a DivideByZero error and then you would call foo somewhere else inside a do-catch, setting up a situation that the DivideByZero error is caught.

Comment: "foo would know to throw a DivideByZero error" is what I want to stay away from.  I want to handle unexpected errors.

Comment: The final catch in a do-catch loop is there to catch unexpected errors, like the default case in a switch. Is this what you're asking about?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96743/discussion-between-steven-wexler-and-tnev).

Comment: @tnev that's exactly what I tried.  The catch block is never hit.  The app just crashes.

Comment: You simply can not handle fatal errors in Swift. You can only avoid them by not passing illegal values.